# How to add a left arrow like tooltip in the boxes coming from loop in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have some link Click-1,Click-2 etc, when I click on it corresponding box will show. That box is already having position absolute. I want to add a small arrow on the left side of each box which should be like tooltip, I already used css shapes but it cannot possible with same div,for that I need to create other div and to put position absolute,but it was not coming correctly.Here is the code below. https://plnkr.co/edit/jv7uKHlryMnkJgK9wVM6?p=preview

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data" >
       <div ng-click="setActiveItem(x)" class="id">Click-{{x.id}}</div>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ssssssssssss
       <div class="arrow_box name" ng-show="activeItem==x">
       <h3>{{x.name}}<h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       <h3>{{x.name}}<h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       <h3>{{x.name}}<h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

### CSS

```
ul li{
list-style-type:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul{
margin:0;
}
.maindiv{
position:relative;
}
.name{
position: absolute;
    left: 97px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 61px;
    height: 202px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 24%;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.id,name{
float:left;
}
```

### SCRIPT

```
var data = [{"name":"name1","title":"title1","id":"1"},{"name":"name2","title":"title2","id":"2"},{"name":"name3","title":"title3","id":"3"}];
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = data;

  $scope.setActiveItem = function(item){
     $scope.activeItem = item;
  }

  // show first on page load
  // $scope.activeItem = data[0];

});// Code goes here
```

Comment: what about using bootstrap tooltip ? is that can resolve you issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this css snippet in your style.css:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Instead of **name** css class , call the  **arrow_box** class

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data" >
       <span ng-click="setActiveItem(x)" class="id">Click-{{x.id}}</span>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ssssssssssss<span class="arrow_box" ng-show="activeItem==x">{{x.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Check here [plunker code](https://embed.plnkr.co/Wc30sk/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,when I put div tag instead of span tag or if I put block element inside span it is not working because its changed to position relative from absolute, It should not disturb the text also 'sssss',the box should overlapp on it.I have updated my plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/jv7uKHlryMnkJgK9wVM6?p=preview